# Automatically detect keyboard language

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using multiple keyboards with different keyboard layouts in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/177305/using-multiple-keyboards-with-different-keyboard-layouts-in-windows)

I have a `English-US` keyboard and a `Portuguese-PT` keyboard. Is it possible for Windows7 to automatically detect from which keyboard the key presses are coming and adjust accordingly?

Comment: Whats a "PT keyboard"?

Comment: Portuguese-PT as in Portuguese from Portugal which is different from the Portuguese from Brazil layout (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Portuguese_.28Brazil.29)

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/177305/using-multiple-keyboards-with-different-keyboard-layouts-in-windows. It says it's impossible, unfortunately.

Comment: You could however have a shortcut key on both keyboards (ex. SHIFT+F12) that switch the keyboard layout to the keyboard layout of that keyboard.