# A second keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I find it annoying to look up at my alt chart to find the perfect symbol so I wanted to know If i could modify the buttons on a second keyboard without hacks. I dowloaded a software clled MSKLC.exe but I cant run it because of another problem.

Comment: MSKLC is very good. Why can't you run it?

Comment: Microsoft .NET error (Its really bad) but would MSKLC.exe help me?

Comment: Yes it would. Perhaps you simply need to update to .net 4.0 package?

Comment: great once microsoft fixes that Ill do it (post that as an answer and I will mark it as teh answer)

Comment: Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator will let you create a new keyboard layout. However, Windows doesn't have a way to assign unique layouts to multiple keyboards: If you connect two keyboards to your computer, they will both use the current keyboard layout. For a possible solution, see [Using multiple keyboards with different keyboard layouts in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/177305/using-multiple-keyboards-with-different-keyboard-layouts-in-windows).

Comment: @JakeInc Can you be specific about the error you received? What does it say? You have to install the NET update yourself. See: https://www.microsoft.com/net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't seem to think you could run keyboards with different layouts on the same system. However you *could* get a keyboard (or mouse) with macro keys (and a software for that), unless you needed a *lot* of them - you could then code those extra keys (or even keys you don't use often) as additional keys. The Razer Keyboard i have allows me to do this, and i know some MMORPG mice which have 6 or even 9 spare keys.