# How to Configure Windows 7 to automatically change keyboard layout when switching keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using multiple keyboards with different keyboard layouts in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/177305/using-multiple-keyboards-with-different-keyboard-layouts-in-windows)

I have a keyboard (G15) that I use for gaming, I've created a custom layout for it with microsoft keyboard layout creator, my notebook and G15 have different layouts, what I want ask from Windows 7 is to automatically change keyboard layout if I connect G15, and change to default if disconnected. Is it possible ?

Comment: I was able to find a potential solution in this other thread:
http://superuser.com/questions/177305/using-multiple-keyboards-with-different-keyboard-layouts-in-windows