# Change keyboard layout automatically based on keyboard being used (Win)

Tags: windows, keyboard, automation, layout

My laptop has an Italian keyboard layout, but after moving to the US I'm using it with a US  keyboard attached via USB when at work.
When on the go I'm on the IT keyboard and constantly switching layout for every open program with left-alt+right-shift is becoming a real pain.

Anyone knows of a tool that automatically changes the keyboard layout based on the physical keyboard being used?

Comment: You haven't said what OS you are running.  i.e. Windows has built-in tools for changing the keyboard layout, under the language / regionalization controls.  Those changes would presumably carry over to whatever programs you were running.

Comment: In Windows the default for cycling through the installed layouts are the left Alt and Shift Key. However that does not automatically detect the Keyboardlayout. The way some versions of Linux "detect" the used Keyboard (press certain keys) tells me there maybe is no way to know for the OS which keyboard layout you have. Also you change the layout per application that way, not for the whole system.

Comment: @Debra OS specified, thanks for pointing that out. What I'm looking for is something that would change the keyboard layout automatically (like: upon pressing a key on the IT or US keyboard). Going under language / reg controls (or event using the keyb shortcut) is a real pain when you have to switch often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in another superuser question, which makes this a duplicate.
Here is the link: [Using multiple keyboards with different keyboard layouts in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/177305/using-multiple-keyboards-with-different-keyboard-layouts-in-windows)