# Extra keyboard for hotkeys - Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I found how to have different layouts on 2 different connected keyboards [here](https://superuser.com/questions/75817/two-keyboards-on-one-computer-when-i-write-with-a-i-want-a-us-keyboard-layout), but I want to re-map the keys on a second keyboard for web development. Preferably, I'd have keys that would type out code snippets. However, if I can even re-map the keys on the second keyboard, I can do the code snippet hot-keys inside of my IDE.

Another idea/option would be to see the keyboard as a game controller. Is this possible? I currently use [AntiMicro](https://github.com/Ryochan7/antimicro) to use a keypad for window/virtual desktop hot-keys.