# How to manually remap keyboard mapping on different keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-layout, fn-key, ubuntu-20.04

I have an external keyboard connected by USB on my laptop. I would like to remap the keycodes of the external keyboard without changing the keycodes of the laptop keyboard.

To be more specific, I want the function keys (F1-F12) to behave as they are, not the functionalities like turning volume/brightness up/down.

Let's use F12 as example. When I'm focusing on Chrome,

```
Laptop keyboard  : F12    -> open console
                   FN+F12 -> volume up

External keyboard: F12    -> volume up
                   FN+F12 -> open console
```

Totally messed up. When I use `xev`, here's the output

```
External keyboard (xev)
----------------------------------------
[F11] (volume down)
FocusOut event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
----------------------------------------
[F12] (volume up)
FocusOut event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 

----------------------------------------
[FN+F12]
KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x5d1, subw 0x0, time 16400865, (-850,446), root:(706,511),
    state 0x0, keycode 96 (keysym 0xffc9, F12), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x5d1, subw 0x0, time 16400985, (-850,446), root:(706,511),
    state 0x0, keycode 96 (keysym 0xffc9, F12), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

As you can see, F11 (volume down) and F12 (volume up) have no difference in `xev`. But in `acpi_listen`, I have

```
External keyboard (acpi_listen)
----------------------------------------
[F11]
button/volumedown VOLDN 00000080 00000000 K
----------------------------------------
[F12]
button/volumeup VOLUP 00000080 00000000 K
```

`xinput -list` of the external keyboard (not sure why there are 2 entries)

```
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ ...
    ↳ SONiX USB DEVICE                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SONiX USB DEVICE                          id=23   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

---

**My question is, how can I change the key mapping of the external keyboard without interfering with the laptop keyboard?** The external keyboard does not have 'FN-lock' or anything like that.

Thank you in advance.

---

PS: Actually, the Win key and ALT_L key have swapped, but I assume if the problem above is solved, this will be too.

PS2: I have read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/75817/two-keyboards-on-one-computer-when-i-write-with-a-i-want-a-us-keyboard-layout) but it only changes the layout of the keyboard to another pre-defined layout mapping, which doesn't solve my problem.

---

EDIT 1:
I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and kernel 5.4.0-33-generic. My laptop is an Asus UX550.